# How do I implement train_test_split in this code?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, train-test-split

```
# Load training and validation sets
ds_train_ = image_dataset_from_directory(
    '../input/car-or-truck/train', 
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='binary',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True,
)
ds_valid_ = image_dataset_from_directory(
    '../input/car-or-truck/valid',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='binary',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=False,
)

print(ds_train_)
print(ds_valid_)
# Data Pipeline
def convert_to_float(image, label):
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    return image, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
ds_train = (
    ds_train_
    .map(convert_to_float)
    .cache()
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)
ds_valid = (
    ds_valid_
    .map(convert_to_float)
    .cache()
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)

print(ds_train)
print(ds_valid)
```

The current code is based on 2 files of a train set and a valid set, which are already separated. However, I want to edit this code so that it starts with a single file consisting of all images, then uses train_test_split to randomly split the file into train/valid and then implement it. How can I implement train_test_split to this code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the dataset from any directory.. use image_dataset_from_directory from tensorflow

And use subset feature

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory

path="<put path here>"

training_data=image_dataset_from_directory(
   path,
   image_size=(<put your image size here>),
   batch_size=batch_size,
   validation_split=0.2 ,# as per your need
   subset='training'

)
 validation_data=image_dataset_from_directory(
     path,
     image_size=(<put your image size here>),
     batch_size=batch_size,
     validation_split=0.2 ,# as per your need
     subset='validation'
```

)

You  can add other args like labels,color mode and many others inside the " ( )" .. but it should be same on both place..

If you have any more query , refer to this [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory)

If you got satisfied or your query is clear... upvote...
Otherwise let me know in Comments